# What is the difference between RECEIVE_MMS nad RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH?

Tags: android, android-permissions

What is the difference between RECEIVE_MMS and RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
```

Comment: What is WAP ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Docs

**RECEIVE_MMS**

> Allows an application to monitor incoming MMS messages. Protection
>   level: dangerous Constant Value: "android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"

**RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH**

> Allows an application to receive WAP push messages. Protection level:
>   dangerous Constant Value: "android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"

*Now what is wap push?*
You must have seen SMS's of different types without realizing it. e.g. alert messages that auto-popup on the screen, commissioning messages that you get from your telco (they don't show up on the screen; they set your phone parameters for you), among other types.

So `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>` allows you to monitor incoming MMS messages whereas `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>` allows you to recieve WAP push messages.